# C# Need to deep copy an object

Tags: c#, .net, object, constructor, clone

I need to deep copy an object from a class that I made to another object from the same class, I dont want to shallow copy and I dont want to use the serialization method
is there any other easy methods to use??

Comment: Thanks all for the answers =)

Answer (score 1):

One cheap way is to serialize it then deserialize it straight back using binary serialization.

```
MyObject myobj = new MyObject(); 
// ...

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(ms, myObj);

MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());

var myobj2 = (MyObject)formatter.Deserialize(ms2);
```

Comment: I hear you. But if you have a truly complex object graph, this might be the safest way to pull it off. Custom "deep copy" code can easily miss fields as you add them.

Comment: Does the creation of the second stream duplicate all of the data that has been written to the stream?

Comment: @mathepic Yes it does. I didn't realize until after my first response that the first "answer" redirects to a similar solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically They reuse the stream by seeking it to the beginning. However, with release GC and the internals of the MemoryStream it probably reuses the array anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [IClonable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone.aspx) and provide the cloning yourself in the `Clone` method.